# Movie about a board-game that asks the players touchy questions

Tags: identify-this-movie

I would like to identify a Movie I watched on TV in the early or mid 2000s. It was for sure US-made (although I watched a Spanish-dubbed version) and, if I guess correctly, based on clothing style and filming quality, produced in the 90s. It is probably an attempt to piggy-back on *Jumanji* and deals also with a board game that threatens the players, a family that is going through a crisis.

In this particular movie, every now and then a big hologram of a tribal mask will rise in the air and ask the players sensitive questions. If they lie, the game will tele-transport them next to a precipice where they have to cooperate pressing buttons to go back to safety at home. The mask, as I recall, asks the husband if he had an extramarital affair, to which he answers with the truth: No. Later, the wife will congratulate him with a passionate kiss for being faithful. Also, the mask asks the daughter if she had sexual relations in the last year (I don't remember the answer). I remember too that the game cannot be abandoned or destroyed. Once, the son tried to smash it with a hammer and another hologram of a native american man appears and brandishes a menacing spear at him. The son desists and the game resumes.

Plotwise the movie is pretty lame and repetitive. They would lie again and again putting their relatives in danger and the questions test how ideal and up-to-the-moral-standards is the family, but out of curiosity I would like to identify the movie.

Comment: A similar Q was [asked and answered](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93933/movie-about-a-family-who-gets-a-game-from-a-friend-and-are-transported-to-an-old) over at SciFi.SE. You're looking for [Manatu - Nur die Wahrheit rettet dich](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0904099/combined) from 2007 (so I'm afraid it wasn't US after all). Thanks for the detailed Q, though.

Comment: @Walt Thanks! Could you make your comment and answer so I can check this question as solved? Neither made in the US nor filmed in the 90s. And it was produced in 2007, so I couldn't have seen it in the early 2000s. Memory plays its tricks man...

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As was [answered over at Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93933/movie-about-a-family-who-gets-a-game-from-a-friend-and-are-transported-to-an-old), you're looking for the German TV movie [Manatu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0904099/combined) from 2007, in which a family plays a strange board game where you must tell the truth. It contains everything you mention (the tribal mask holograms, trying to break the game with a hammer etc.). Here's a clip: